# SQL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY only for UNIQUE name field

Tags: mysql, sql

So i made an auto incrementing primary key for my family table of the presidents of America, now some presidents are listed multiple times because they got remarried (f.e. Tyler J) but that results in Tyler J having a 10 and 11 as pres_id. So how do i make the primary key auto_increment only for unique name fields? link to picture of the table: http://puu.sh/fN6KD/e7c5e03c7a.png

And now that i've created the pres_id column allready can i adjust it?

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 1):

The fix to this is normalization.

Since a president can have multiple spouses, those marriage details should be moved to a separate table, and they'd reference the president via the `pres_id`. If you repeat the `pres_id` in your current table based on name, it wouldn't be a Primary Key anymore.

Your tables could be:

```
tbl_POTUS (Pres_ID,Pres_Name,Birth_Yr,Death_Yr)
tbl_FLOTUS (Spouse_ID,Pres_ID,Spouse_Name,Mar_Year,Nr_Children)
```

Comment: Ah yeah ofc it wouldn't be a primary key anymore if two records had the same key... Thanks